# Performing a docx to pdf conversion in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, aspose.words

I have a requirement to generate pdf documents from word templates and send e-mail as an attachment. We are planning to develop the functionality as a kind of micro service in Azure Service Fabric. We have done POC with Aspose.Words for .NET in a normal ASp.NET Web Api application and it is working fine. Now I need to make it working in Azure Service Fabric probably in a stateless web api service. Since it is an Azure VM and SF has a sandbox environment, I have below queries
1) Is it possible to perform such action in SF since this library demands the application to run under Windows Azure Full Trust. https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/About+Aspose.Words+and+Windows+Azure

2) Is it possible to access file system in SF, since I need to save the pdf temporarily before sending e-mail attachment.

3) Is SF is the right place to perform such operation or do I need to consider Azure Web App?

Since I can not find any example related to this, any feedback from SF Experts will be helpful.

Comment: 3) IMO, no. And therefore the other 2 questions don't need an answer. What are your thoughts that lead you to think that ASF would be a good fit? Setting up a ASF cluster just to handle document conversions seems like a lot of overkill.

Comment: Hi Peter. I have a couple of REST Services (Stateless Web Api SF Template) running in SF Cluster as micro services(not pure play). Now one of them need to generate a receipt in pdf format and send the same as e-mail. I can create an Azure Web App and try the same. I have a cluster with a VM's already, hence thought about trying the same.

Comment: Maybe an azure function is a viable way to go. Cheap, scales well.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1) and 2), you only need to run your application under Windows Azure *Full Trust* because Aspose.Words needs to enumerate and read *TrueType fonts* which are installed on the machine. Alternatively, if you are unable to run your application at *full trust*, you can specify your own folders where Aspose.Words will look for fonts and place your fonts in there. For details on how to achieve this, see the [How-to: Specify True Type Font Location article](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/True+Type+Fonts#TrueTypeFonts-HowtoSpecifyTrueTypeFontsLocation).

Secondly, instead of saving the PDF temporarily to file system, you may save it inside Memory by using the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfSaveOptions opts = new PdfSaveOptions();
doc.Save(pdfStream, opts);
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Hello Awais, Thanks for your reply. I was able to  generated pdf from word template via Aspose.Words reporting engine and send e-mail with pdf attachment from an Azure App Service. Yes instead of saving to memory, I saved to memory stream and send e-mail via SendGrid cloud service. I am still looking whether the same is possible in a Service Fabric application. Any case studies you are aware of?

Comment: I am afraid, I am not aware of any case studies related to Service Fabric applications. You can try it on your end. Alternatively, you may also try [Aspose.Words for Cloud](https://www.aspose.com/products/words/cloud) REST API. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.